# Why does mongoose always add an s to the end of my collection name

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

For example, this code results in a collection called "datas" being created

```
var Dataset = mongoose.model('data', dataSchema);
```

And this code results in a collection called "users" being created

```
var User = mongoose.model('user', dataSchema);
```

Thanks

Comment: It's the convention in Rails. You have object "user", you store it in "users" collection. It's the same in Mongoose, I guess.

Comment: Yeah, interestingly enough var Dataset = mongoose.model('datas', dataSchema); results in a collection called datas.

Comment: Seems that pluralizing logic is not that dumb (or smart, depends on what you expected). I'm sure you can find out how it works exactly (find the source).

Comment: @SergioTulentsev, that is not ruby, but it works in the same way https://github.com/LearnBoost/mongoose/blob/master/lib/utils.js

Comment: Been there, Done That. Thanks for asking the question :)

Comment: Just for the record. Data is plural, singular of data is datum

Answer (score 278, accepted):

Mongoose is trying to be smart by making your collection name plural. You can however force it to be whatever you want:

`var dataSchema = new Schema({..}, { collection: 'data' })`

Comment: I don't understand how adding a "s" makes the framework more intelligent, IMHO, that is a bad idea. Apart from that mongoose is an awesome framework.

Comment: its an old poor choice that breaks backward compatibility if taken out. so we've chosen to stick with it.

Comment: WHat do you meant? If I want to use singular collection name instead of pluralized I'll get issues?

Comment: @Vadorequest - No, it means that if someone updated their mongo instance, their code would break.

Comment: it lowercased it and added an s. the first one was acceptable. For those like me who now have data in the wrong collection it's time to rename it

Comment: it doesn't just add an 's' but it makes the correct plural of the name. Try for instances with 'mouse', you'll get a collection named 'mice' or with 'person' you'll get 'people'. It was driving me crazy to understand from where these names came from :-)

Comment: this is a really poor design but now i kinda want to know how mongoose does irregular plurals...

Comment: This is very crazy now which name do you use to query your collection espically when you have to do it from another interface ?

Comment: Idiotic IMO. I was wondering why using references to the "history" schema was leading to updates in "histories" without any sort of aliasing going on in the scripts. I eventually came to the conclusion that Mongoose was doing something "clever", hence I found myself here, but it's a non-intuitive default behaviour.

Comment: I was freaking out, because I defined "brush" and there was a collection named "brushes". I was trying to find where I'd defined that for almost half an hour and didn't found anything. I thought: "Maybe it's smart and adds that. Probably not, but let's se.... FUUUUUUU"

Comment: Yes, very confusing. It's even more of a bad idea when it isn't even consistent. If you have a name ending with a number, it doesn't add an 's', and if you add an s yourself it doesn't add one either.

Comment: what if we wanted to pass 'bus' as the parameter, mongoose will then treat like 'buss' XD XD XD. mongoose if deliberately want to grammar then it should use all the grammar  rules, right?

Comment: Just wasted an hour of my life due to this. It's really dumb. Change code essentially without telling the coder. Lame!

Comment: My collection is ALREADY PLURALIZED: "content"

Comment: hate this, i feel like this is hidden convention and opinionated, i spend hours to check why my controller cannot access my database

Answer (score 64):

API structure of mongoose.model is this:

```
Mongoose#model(name, [schema], [collection], [skipInit])
```

What mongoose do is that, When no collection argument is passed, Mongoose produces a collection name by pluralizing the model name. If you don't like this behavior, either pass a collection name or set your schemas collection name option.

Example:

```
var schema = new Schema({ name: String }, { collection: 'actor' });
```

or

```
schema.set('collection', 'actor');
```

or

```
var collectionName = 'actor'
var M = mongoose.model('Actor', schema, collectionName);
```

Answer (score 56):

Starting from mongoose 5.x you can disable it completely:

```
mongoose.pluralize(null);
```

Comment: Best solution, becuase we don't have to define both model name and collection name.

Comment: This is definitely the best approach.

Comment: It took me some hours to learn about this kind of smartness of Mongoose. Anyway - glad I found this solution. BTW: It also avoids automatic lower casing of collection names.

Comment: Careful, this doesn't only stop pluralize, it also prevents toLowerCase()

Comment: how to do this on connection object? which is done using createConnection method?

Answer (score 12):

You can simply add a string as a third argument to define the actual name for the collection. Extending your examples, to keep names as `data` and `user` respectively:

```
var Dataset = mongoose.model('data', dataSchema, 'data');

var User = mongoose.model('user', dataSchema, 'user');
```

Comment: it's works for me. Took me soo long. I'm glad to found this solution.

Answer (score 9):

```
//Mongoose's definition file. NOT your model files
1 const mongoose = require("mongoose");
2 mongoose.pluralize(null);
```

Adding the line`mongoose.pluralize(null)` in your Mongoose file will prevent collection name pluralization. You don't need to add this line to your model files.

As seen [here](https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/issues/5947).

Comment: Thanks. I have used above 2 lines in common file & imported it. This simplified code compared to writing different 3rd param in `moongose.model`.

Answer (score 2):

You can add the collection name as third parameter. See the example using Typescript:

```
import DataAccess = require('../DataAccess');
import IUser = require("../../Models/Interfaces/IUser");

var mongoose = DataAccess.mongooseInstance;
var mongooseConnection = DataAccess.mongooseConnection;

class UserSchema {
        static get schema () {
        var schema =  mongoose.Schema({
            _id : {
                type: String
            },
            Name: {
                type: String,
                required: true
            },
            Age: {
                type: Number,
                required: true
            }
        });

        return schema;
    }
}
var schema:any = mongooseConnection.model<IUser>("User", 
UserSchema.schema,"User");
export = schema;
```

Answer (score 1):

At the end of defining your schema on the next line
Use this code

```
module.exports = mongoose.model("State", "StateSchema", "state")
```

Assuming that your state is what you want to use on your db to avoid s as states

[Click the  link to view the picture properly](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XShpJ.jpg)

Answer (score -2):

Mongoose compiles a model for you when you run this command

```
var schema = new mongoose.Schema({ name: 'string', size: 'string' });
var child = mongoose.model('child', schema);
```

The first argument is the singular name of the collection your model is for. **Mongoose automatically looks for the plural, *lowercased* version of your model name.** Thus, for the example above, the model child is for the children collection in the database.

**Note:** The `.model()` function makes a copy of schema. Make sure that you've added everything you want to schema, including hooks, before calling `.model()`!

Comment: you're recreating the problem?

Comment: Nope! I'm not!!