# Mongoose plural collection definition

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I'm trying to create different collections based on a specific `id`, the way that I do that is:

```
db.save({...}, 'collection_' + id).then(function() {
    deferred.resolve();
});
```

This works fine, I can see the new collection in my database.

However, when I'm trying to load this data, it doesn't work because mongoose forces it to be plurar.

```
var Items = mongoose.model('collection_' + id, MySchema);
Items.count(function(err, count) {
    console.log(count); = 0
});
```

The `id` is completely dynamic and varies on every request I make, how can I stop `mongoose` from adding an 's' to every collection name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can explicitly set the collection name for a model as follows:

```
var collectionName = 'collection_' + id;
var Items = mongoose.model(collectionName, MySchema, collectionName);
//                         ^Change this if you want      ^This sets the collection name
```

Check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24464025/2043580) for more ways to set the collection name.

Comment: Ah, I saw that answer too late. This works perfectly!