# Adding a new navigation tab in CMS (keystone JS)

Tags: content-management-system, keystonejs

I am new in KeystoneJS and was trying to add a new navigation tab in the admin panel , so for the same i made changes in the **keystone.js** file and added the required navigation tab in the code

"**keystone.set('nav', {
....
});**"

but after making changes in it and then running the code i get an error ***Unknown keystone list "newTab"***

Comment: Why is this marked down without a comment? It seems most of these Admin customization questions are. There isn't a clear answer already available so I DON'T believe the question should be penalized... I mean.. yes the correct syntax is in the docs but clearly some users can't find it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know the name of your model, but the correct syntax is:

```
keystone.set('nav', {
    '<tab-name>': '<modelname>'
});
```

Where tab name can be anything, and modelname should be either the exact (case sensitive!) same name as your model name or a lower case plural version of it.

For example:
*Your model:* **Artwork.js**

```
var Artwork = new keystone.List('Artwork', { ... });
```

*Your navigation definition:*

```
keystone.set('nav', {
    'art': 'Artwork'
});
```

OR

```
keystone.set('nav', {
    'art': 'artworks'
});
```

Comment: I updated to the lower case plural version of the model and it fixed bug, but I'm curious why it has to be plural version? @JasperV

Comment: @Yao: As far as I know, it is a Mongoose thing: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10547118/why-does-mongoose-always-add-an-s-to-the-end-of-my-collection-name
Keystone supports it as well... Although you can also override the collection name, see this comment on the github page: https://github.com/keystonejs/keystone/issues/292#issuecomment-40897315