# Mongodb: findById() returns no value

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

The following `findById()` returns `null` even though the `id` exists in the database:

```
router.get('/product/:id', function (req, res) {

console.log("product id = " + req.params.id);

//produces product id = 596161e1734d1d25634366ce

var id = req.params.id;

Product.findById({_id: req.params.id})
    .exec(function (err, product) {
        if (err) {
            console.error('Error retrieving all product by id!');
        } else {
            console.log('server product = ' + JSON.stringify(product));
            res.json(product);
        }
    })
})
```

Target document in database:

```
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "596161e1734d1d25634366ce"
    },
    "producttype": "stove",
    "name": "30 in. 4.8 cu. ft. Electric Range in Stainless Steel",
    "brand": "Amana",
    "model": "AER6303MFS",
}
```

Model:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const ProductSchema = new Schema({
    _id: String,
    productType: String,
    name: String,
    brand: String,
    model: String,
    price: Number,
    discount: Number,
    description: String,
    rating: Number,
    sku: String,
    warranty: String,
});

var Product = mongoose.model('Product', ProductSchema, 'product');
module.exports=Product;
```

Answer (score 2):

Try to remove _id from your ProductSchema. Id will be automatically generated by the mongodb. After that try using

```
Product.find({_id: req.params.id})
    .exec(function (err, product) {
        if (err) {
            console.error('Error retrieving all product by id!');
        } else {
            console.log('server product = ' + JSON.stringify(product));
            res.json(product);
        }
    })
})
```

or if you want to use find by id then use

```
Product.findById(req.params.id)
    .exec(function (err, product) {
        if (err) {
            console.error('Error retrieving all product by id!');
        } else {
            console.log('server product = ' + JSON.stringify(product));
            res.json(product);
        }
    })
})
```

Comment: Worked like a charm. Thank you.

Comment: How do I do that?

Comment: There should be symbol of tick below upvote and downvote of your question.

Answer (score 1):

Taken from the [docs](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html), have you tried passing just the `req.params.id` instead of an object? like so:

```
Product.findById(req.params.id)
    .exec(function (err, product) {
        if (err) {
            console.error('Error retrieving all product by id!');
        } else {
            console.log('server product = ' + JSON.stringify(product));
            res.json(product);
        }
    })
})
```

Comment: Can you include your schema?

Comment: I have shown a partial schema in my original question above.

Comment: I mean the mongoose schema. Something like this http://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html

Comment: My guess is it is related to the Collection name that is used by Mongoose. Refer link here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10547118/why-does-mongoose-always-add-an-s-to-the-end-of-my-collection-name

Comment: I've added it to the original post above.

Comment: By the way, this works on the same schema: Product.find({ brand: brand })

Comment: This is the right answer, also you mustn't put the _id path on your document schema!