# mongodb only some collections are returning data and some are not though they are on same DB using nodeJS

Tags: node.js, mongodb, cloud

I have created few collections on cloud mongodb on the same DB. Only some collections are returning values and others are not (just blank []) using nodeJS. No error msg or exceptions. 
I tested on mongodb shell and it shows data in all the collections.

I used this example to create my project. You can get full code from here. 
http://programmerblog.net/nodejs-mongodb-rest-api/

### Here is my code in app, router, model, controller js files:

app.js

```
...
var  mongodburi = "mongodb+srv://myID:myPassword@cluster0-qabk1.mongodb.net/onlinestore";
.....
var routes = require('./restapi/routes/productRoutes');
```

---

productRoutes.js

```
...
 var product = require('../controllers/productController');
app.route('/products')
    .get(product.products)
----
```

---

productModel.js

```
    'use strict';
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;
var Schema = new Schema({
  product_name: { type: String, Required:  'Product name cannot be left blank.' },
  price:    { type: String,     Required:  'Product price cannot be left blank.'},
  category: { type: String ,    Required:  'Product category cannot be left blank'}
});
module.exports = mongoose.model('products', Schema);
```

---

productController.js

```
'use strict';

var mongoose = require('mongoose'),
    Product = mongoose.model('products');

exports.products = function(req, res) {
  Product.find({}, function(err, product) {
    if (err)
      res.send(err);
    res.json(product);
  });
};
```

---

Collection 1: products - I am getting the values
Collection 2: techinfo - I am not getting the values
Collection 3: tests - I am getting the values

I have created all these collections in the same way. 
I am just changing the collection name in code at 2 places:
1st. productModel.js at line module.exports = mongoose.model('**techinfo**', Schema);
2nd: productController.js at line Product = mongoose.model('**techinfo**');

**why it works for products and tests and not for techinfo collection?** (I even tried creating more collections but it's inconsistent).

Answer (score 0):

Can't believe this framework does this.
When you dont' pass the collection name, by default it adds 's' at the end of model name you are passing. That's why I was able to get the data from products and tests collections but not from techinfo.

This is what I was doing initially. That's why it was adding additional 's' by default.

```
module.exports = mongoose.model('techinfo', techInfoSchema);
```

If you want to call a particular collection, pass it like this:

```
module.exports = mongoose.model('techinfo', techInfoSchema, 'techinfo')
```

More info at:
[Why does mongoose always add an s to the end of my collection name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10547118/why-does-mongoose-always-add-an-s-to-the-end-of-my-collection-name)