# Node mongoose model first argument

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm learning node and mongo and use mongoose for my modeling.

In the mongoose docs it says that `mongoose.model`, the first argument is singular name of the collection of your model. I find this hard to understand.

1. My db name is `CRMdb` is this also the collection name?
2. My model looks like this `const Contact = mongoose.model('Contact', ContactSchema);`, How does mongoose know automatically detect for the plural version of my model name?
   `

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10547118/why-does-mongoose-always-add-an-s-to-the-end-of-my-collection-name

Answer (score 2):

1. A collection is like a table, not a db, so no.
2. You can also do it like this `const Contact = mongoose.model('Contact', ContactSchema, 'contacts');` (in this case the collection name is `contacts`). Not really sure how they create the plural, but I don't really think it matters.