# How to resolve MissingSchemaError in mongodb using mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I am creating a `schema` model dynamically. So I am not able to use this `model` for other events like a record `save`, `update`, `remove`, etc. If I use that I am getting this error:

> Error:  MissingSchemaError: Schema hasn't been registered for model
>   "XYZ".  Use mongoose.model(name, schema)

I do not know why it is coming to this error. I have tried many times but not working. Please help to resolve this issue?

schemamodel.js:

```
    /* model.js */
 'use strict';
 var mongoose = require('mongoose'),
     Schema = mongoose.Schema;

 function dynamicModel(suffix) {
     var collsName = suffix.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + suffix.slice(1);
     var newSchema = new Schema({
         product_name: {
             type: String
         }
     }, {
         versionKey: false
     });
     try {
         if (mongoose.model(collsName)) return mongoose.model(collsName);
     } catch (e) {
         if (e.name === 'MissingSchemaError') {
             return mongoose.model(collsName, newSchema, suffix);
         }
     }
 }
 module.exports = dynamicModel;
```

data.controller.js:

```
module.exports.newCollection = (req, res, next) => {
    var collectionName = req.query.collectionName;
    var NewModel;
    mongoose.connection.db.listCollections().toArray(function(err, names) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
        } else {
            names.forEach(function(e, i, a) {
                if (e.name == collectionName.toLowerCase()) {
                    console.log("The collection already exists");
                } else {
                    console.log("The collection not exists");
                    NewModel = require(path.resolve('./models/schemamodel.js'))(collectionName);
                    NewModel.create({}, function(err, doc) {});
                }
            });
        }
    });
}
//get data collection from collection 
module.exports.getCollectionData = (req, res, next) => {
    let collection = req.query.collection;
    let data = mongoose.model(collection); // here getting MissingSchemaError
    data.find({}, function(err, docs) {
        if (err) {
            console.log('ss' + err);
            return;
        } else {
            console.log("Successful loaded");
        }
    });
}
```

api call:

```
http://localhost:3000/api/getCollectionData?collection=Apply
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `mongoose.model(...)` you need the DB connection `db.model(...)`

```
 /* model.js */
 'use strict';
 var mongoose = require('mongoose'),
     Schema = mongoose.Schema;
 const db = mongoose.createConnection(
      "mongodb://localhost:27017/datadetails",
      {
        useNewUrlParser: true,
        useUnifiedTopology: true
      }
  );
 function dynamicModel(suffix) {
     var collsName = suffix.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + suffix.slice(1);
     var newSchema = new Schema({
         product_name: {
             type: String
         }
     }, {
         versionKey: false
     });
     try {
         if (db.model(collsName)) return db.model(collsName);
     } catch (e) {
         if (e.name === 'MissingSchemaError') {
             return db.model(collsName, newSchema, suffix);
         }
     }
 }
 module.exports = dynamicModel;
```

Comment: @PappaS where is your mongodb installed? is it a cluster or does it run locally?

Comment: Mongodb run locally

Comment: @PappaS it should look something like this `mongodb://localhost:27017/myapp`

Comment: @PappaS where `myapp` is your database name

Comment: This is my DB url : mongodb://localhost:27017/datadetails

Comment: @PappaS try it like that

Comment: If i use your code two collection is creating like apple and apples

Comment: @PappaS if you define your collection as `apple` it creates an collection `apples`, it always adds an `s` to the end of the collection name. so everybody knows its plular

Comment: Ya..I know.Anyway is there to avoid s ?

Comment: @PappaS check it out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10547118/why-does-mongoose-always-add-an-s-to-the-end-of-my-collection-name

Comment: Same method i have used..see model(collsName, newSchema, suffix)

Comment: @PappaS i see, but i cant help you either here

Comment: Please help me..Becuase i tried too long time to resolve this issue also i am new in mongoose

Comment: @PappaS you still have the missingSchemaError?

Comment: Yes Some time getting this error: Schema hasn't been registered for model "xyz"

Comment: Till now i am getting this error: Schema hasn't been registered for model "xyz"

Comment: Please..Give me the solution

Comment: @PappaS i am sorry but i cant help you either with a distance diagnostic

Comment: Can you answer for sixtwo25969nine ?