# How to sen data with post methode to mongodb with Express server

Tags: mongodb, express, crud

i want to write data over my Express server with the ´post´ methode to the mongoDB.

i use mongoose to connect to my mongodb with the code:

```
const mongoose=require("mongoose")

const LogInSchema=new mongoose.Schema({
    name:{
        type:String,
        required:true
    },
    password:{
        type:String,
        required:true
    }
})

const user=new mongoose.model("UserList", LogInSchema)

module.exports=user
```

Im also connect to my mongodb with my external script:

```
const mongoose=require("mongoose")

function connectdb() {
    
mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/User")
.then(()=>{
    console.log("connected to db");
})
.catch(()=>{
    console.log("There was a problem");
})}

module.exports = {connectdb};
```

Now i want to write with a post methode the data to the mongodb:

```
  app.post("/signup",async (req,res)=>{
    const data={
        name:req.body.name,
        password:req.body.password,
    }
    console.log(data)
    await user.insertMany([data])
})
```

so, in the mongoShell i can see, that the collection `User` is created, and i can also see in the console th log output from my input.

If i want to look in the collection over the mongosh with `db.User.find()`, there is no data in the collection User.

Is this th right way to write the data to mongodb? `await user.insertMany([data])`

i have also tried it with this endpoint:

```
  app.post("/signup",async (req,res)=>{
    const data = new user(req.body);
    console.log(data)
      try {
    await data.save();
    res.send(data);
  } catch (error) {
    res.status(500).send(error);
  }
})
```

in the Terminal, i can see the data values. The data also rendered on the Browser. But if i show in the database over mongosh in the terminal, the database is empty.

Comment: Yo defined your model schema  name as `UserList` `mongoose.model("UserList",...)`. You can't see the data in `user` collection it should be in  `userlists` collection. Checke `userlists` exists and there has some data.

Comment: `mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/userlist")` this creates the collection userlist, but the collection is empty. Im correct to check the collection woth the command db.userlist.find() in mongosh?

Comment: Try `await user.insertOne(data)`. You're only inserting one record, so use `insertOne` instead of `insertMany`

Comment: You can also check the result of the insert like this `const result = await user.insertOne(data)`, `console.log(result)`

Comment: with `await user.insertOne(data)` i get this error => `TypeError: user.insertOne is not a function.` And with `const result = await user.insertOne(data)`, `console.log(result)` i can see the data in the console => `{ name: 'exampleuser', password: 'examplepassword' }`.

Comment: Sorry, I was thinking of the command for Mongo shell, not mongoose. Try `user.create(data)`

Comment: with `user.create(data)` its also the same problem. The Collection is empty.

Comment: @PRATHEESH you are correct from the beginning. I dont recognize the "s" at the end of `userlists`. I can see the data in the collection `userlists`. But i wonder why mongoose creates a collection with `userlists` and not `userlist` which is defined in `const user=new mongoose.model("userlist", LogInSchema)` ???

Comment: See here...https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10547118/why-does-mongoose-always-add-an-s-to-the-end-of-my-collection-name

Answer (score 0):

Maybe i do a failura in other place in my code, so here the complete code.

my app.js:

```
var express = require("express");
var fs = require("fs");
var https = require("https");
var bodyParser = require("body-parser");
var database=require('./script/connectdb')
var path = require("path");
const user = require("./mongodb");


const app = express();
const port = 80;

//create https server
https
  .createServer(
    {
      key: fs.readFileSync("ssl/privkey.pem"),
      cert: fs.readFileSync("ssl/cert.pem"),
    },
      app
  )
  .listen(443, () => {
    console.log('https server is running on port 443')
  });

// Connect to database
database.connectdb();

//static elements
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/dist'));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

//CRUD
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.send("Hallo")
 res.sendFile(__dirname, 'index.html');
 console.log('funktioniert');
})

app.post("/signup",async (req,res)=>{
  const data={
      name:req.body.name,
      password:req.body.password,
  }
  console.log(data)
  const result = await user.insertOne(data)
  console.log(result)
})

app.post("/login",async (req,res)=>{
const userlist = new user();
userlist.name = req.body.name;
userlist.password = req.body.password;
await userlist.save(function (err, data) {
  if (err) {
      console.log(error);
  }
  else {
      res.send("Data inserted");
  }
});
})
```

my connectdb:

```
const mongoose=require("mongoose")

function connectdb() {
    
mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/userlist")
.then(()=>{
    console.log("Mit mongodb erfolgreich verbunden!");
})
.catch(()=>{
    console.log("Es konnte keine Verbindung hergestellt werden");
})}

module.exports = {connectdb};
```

and mongoose schema (mongodb.js

```
const mongoose=require("mongoose")

const LogInSchema=new mongoose.Schema({
    name:{
        type:String,
        required:true
    },
    password:{
        type:String,
        required:true
    }
})

const user=new mongoose.model("userList", LogInSchema)

module.exports=user
```